# Class already registered as subclass?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error

I'm trying to create an addon. I'm able to run the script from the text editor but when I to try install it via *User Preferences*, I get the following error:

> bpy.utils.register_class(SmoothMonkey) 
> ValueError register_class(...) already registered as a subclass 'SmoothMonkey'

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "3D Simple X",
    "author": "8N Films",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 92, 100),
    "location": "View3D > Toolbar > 3D Simple X",
    "description": "Very Simple and easy! Add everything you want!",
    "wiki_url": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpHUlOmZ2XWhcRk7ykPbWiQ",
    "category": "8N Films",
}

import bpy

class SimplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "3D Simple X"
    bl_idname = "PT_SimplePanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = '8N Films'
   
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
       
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "Add everything you want!")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "Simple & easy!   -8N Films", icon= 'ARMATURE_DATA')
        
        
        
        
class AdderXPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Adder X"
    bl_idname = "PT_AdderXPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = '8N Films'
    bl_parent_id ='PT_SimplePanel'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
   
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
       
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "Add an object", icon= 'OUTLINER_OB_EMPTY')  
        
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.text_add", icon= 'OUTLINER_OB_FONT', text= "Add text")
       
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", icon= 'CUBE', text= "Add cube")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", icon= 'SPHERE', text= "Add sphere")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cone_add", icon= 'CONE', text= "Add cone")
       
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_torus_add", icon= 'MESH_TORUS', text= "Add torus")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.camera_add", icon= 'OUTLINER_OB_CAMERA', text= "Add camera")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.light_add", icon= 'OUTLINER_OB_LIGHT', text= "Add light")
        
        
class ToolPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Tools"
    bl_idname = "PT_ToolPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = '8N Films'
    bl_parent_id='PT_SimplePanel'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
   
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
       
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "Choose your tools", icon= 'TOOL_SETTINGS') 

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "                     X             Y             Z")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.object, "scale")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.modifier_add", icon= 'MODIFIER', text= "Modifier")

        
        
        
        
class ScourceXPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Scource X"
    bl_idname = "PT_ScourceXPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = '8N Films'
    bl_parent_id='PT_SimplePanel'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
   
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
       
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "Add a model", icon= 'FILE_BLEND')
       
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_monkey_add", icon= 'MESH_MONKEY', text= "Add monkey")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.smooth_monkey", icon= 'MONKEY', text= "Add smooth monkey")
        

def main(context):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add()
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subdivision"].levels = 4


class SmoothMonkey(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.smooth_monkey"
    bl_label = "Add Smooth Monkey"


    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SmoothMonkey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimplePanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(AdderXPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ToolPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ScourceXPanel)
       

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SmoothMonkey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimplePanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AdderXPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ToolPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ScourceXPanel)
   

register()

    # test call
    # bpy.ops.mesh.smooth_monkey()
```

**Q:** What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this error?

Comment: Looks like you are registering the same class twice.

Comment: Can I send the py. to you and help me to check?

Comment: Did you quit and restart Blender between the time when you ran it in the script editor and when you tried to install it as an add-on ?

Comment: yes. you can see my script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3j6zdOrycCuR2XAE2NpFKcsRMP2TzHB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi and welcome. I took the liberty and edited your question [according to the standards of  this site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), just roll back my edit if you do not like it for whatever reason. BTW: Please take a minute and read about how this site actually works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When installing an add-on as a `.py` file, Blender automatically looks for and executes the `register` method if there is one. Also, when disabling the add-on, it will automatically execute the `unregister` method.

But since you are already calling `register` in the body of the file, it is executed once when parsing the .py file, and once again by Blender when enabling the add-on. But you can't register the same Panel twice. Thus the error.

Usually what developers do to prevent it is to add an `if` statement that will not execute if the file is not run directly. You just need to add `if __name__ == "__main__":` before your `register()` line. The statement will evaluate to `False` if run from another source than the main file, and to `True` when executed in the Script Editor.

Alternatively you can just get rid of this line if you plan on using the script only as an add-on.

[More on that if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Thank you! I did it. I fix the problem now.

Comment: If that fixed your issue, please consider to accept the answer @8NFilms [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie It means a class is registered twice. It might be a name collision from another addon, or something else. Are you using the autoload file from Jacques Lucke ?